# I Cannot Change CollectionViewCell's UILabel Font with C# on Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have a CollectionView on a ViewController which is a tab of RootTabController. This CollectionView's Cell designed as a .xib:

[image]

**Xib UI:**

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="11762" systemVersion="16D32" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
<device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
    <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
</device>
<dependencies>
    <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
    <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="11757"/>
    <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
</dependencies>
<objects>
    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
    <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
    <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="GridBoxCell" id="cZE-iV-UFb" customClass="GridBoxViewCell">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
        <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="12"/>
                    <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
        </view>
        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.20000000000000001" green="0.031372549019607843" blue="0.38039215686274508" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
        <constraints>
            <constraint firstItem="4" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="cZE-iV-UFb" secondAttribute="top" id="10"/>
            <constraint firstItem="4" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="cZE-iV-UFb" secondAttribute="leading" id="11"/>
            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="4" secondAttribute="bottom" id="12"/>
            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="4" secondAttribute="trailing" id="13"/>
        </constraints>
        <userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
            <userDefinedRuntimeAttribute type="number" keyPath="layer.cornerRadius">
                <real key="value" value="5"/>
            </userDefinedRuntimeAttribute>
        </userDefinedRuntimeAttributes>
        <connections>
            <outlet property="Value_Label" destination="4" id="name-outlet-4"/>
        </connections>
    </collectionViewCell>
</objects>
```

I'm trying to change UıLabel's font via code based on device screen size in point at constructor stage while Xib loading before added into CollectionView:

**Xib Code:**

```
        protected GridBoxViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.

            var selectback_view = new UIView(); // Selectedbackground UIview.

            selectback_view.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(117, 24, 73); // pink Color

            SelectedBackgroundView = selectback_view;  // Selected background assigned.

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.Model.Contains("iPad")) // If a iPad
            {
                Value_Label.Font = UIFont.FromName(".SFUIText", 20f); // Increse font width.
            }

            else // If a iPhone or iPod Touch
            {
                if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width == 414 && UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 736) // a iPhone Plus 5.5 in point
                {
                    Value_Label.Font = UIFont.FromName(".SFUIText", 16f); // Increse font width.
                }

                if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width == 375 && UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height == 667) // a iPhone 4.7 in point
                {
                    Value_Label.Font = UIFont.FromName(".SFUIText", 14f); // Increse font width.
                }

            }
}
```

**However, this line gives NullReferenceException:**

> Value_Label.Font = UIFont.FromName(".SFUIText", 14f); // Increse font width.

An UIBarButton "Done" located top of the keyboard adding the value inputted on UITextBox to the GridViewDataSource based on LinkedList. And refreshing data of CollectionView shows the squares.

It was working at the beginning but it is not working now. I could not figure out why it did not work now.Also notice that, xib runs without problem 4" iPhones like SE because I don't code any constraint for it, it uses default font. I'll be happy if you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the `awakeFromNib` method and assign the font in that method.